# Cannot specify my own counts while making bar plot accumulating to 100% in GGplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

First of all, I know about the position = "fill" feature and I have even made a successful plot of my raw data.
With this code

```
g <- ggplot(results, aes(Class))
g + geom_bar(aes(fill = Rating), position = "fill")
```

Looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEUrx.png)

However, when I want to plot the modelled data, I cannot get it to cooperate.

Here is an example of the data

```
class <- (c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4), rep(3,4)))
rating <- rep(c(1,2,3,4),3)
proportion <-  c(0.3304, 0.4241, 0.1305, 0.1150,
              0.4119, 0.4016, 0.1026, 0.0839,
              0.2831, 0.4279, 0.1493, 0.1397)

df <- data.frame(class,proportion,rating)
df$class <- as.factor(df$class) df$rating <- as.factor(df$rating)

g <- ggplot(df, aes(class))
g + geom_bar(aes(fill = proportion),
    position = "fill")
```

But this gives me [this kind of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5DEm.png). I have been messing around for a while now, but have not found a solution.

Are there some of you people who know what to do? Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The second sentence of the documentation for `?geom_bar`: "If you want the heights of the bars to represent values in the data, use geom_col instead.".

Comment: try ggplot(df, aes(x=class, y=proportion, fill=rating)) + geom_bar(position = "fill", stat="identity")

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly map `proportion` to the y-axis, and fill according to rating. As joran pointed out, you can either use `geom_col` or the outdated `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(class, proportion, fill = as.factor(rating))) +
  geom_col()
```